# Why does using pdfbox library in java one pdf form can be readed and other one can not be?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox library in Java to read pdf forms and recognize fields and value in each field (please see below code).

```
System.out.println("- - - - - - - - -");
File file = new File("file.pdf");
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
PDDocumentCatalog catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm form = catalog.getAcroForm();
PDFieldTree fields = form.getFieldTree();

for (PDField field : fields) {
    String name = field.getPartialName();
    Object value = field.getValueAsString();
    System.out.print(name);
    System.out.print(" -> ");
    System.out.print(value);
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("- - - - - - - - -");
```

The code is working with no problem with [this pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK1cE.png), and shows:

```
- - - - - - - - -
test -> 1234
- - - - - - - - -
```

but doesn't work with [this pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoxdS.png), and shows only:

```
- - - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - - -
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger. Please help yourself to some complementary 

debugging techniques. Looks like your `catalog` or `form` or `fields` variables are empty since second PDF file has a different structure

Comment: Unfortunately you only shared images of the PDF, not the PDFs themselves. As the images cannot be inspected for PDF internals, it is difficult to answer concisely. Be aware, though, that there are different types of forms found in PDFs, AcroForms and XFA forms; PDFBox natively only supports AcroForms. One possible cause for your issue is, therefore, that you in some PDFs deal with AcroForms and in some with XFA forms.